Wireguard connection to localhost via VPN refused
In order to access my webserver (behind CGNAT on my home PC), I established a wireguard tunnel between my home PC (wireguard IP 10.8.0.3) and a VPS (wireguard IP 10.8.0.1 and public IP 11.22.33.44). I also have a domain (my.domain) that is associated with the VPS' public IP.
Wireguard conf on the VPS
[Interface]
Address = 10.8.0.1/24
ListenPort = 51820
PrivateKey = PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP

[Peer]
## my home pc
PublicKey = QQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQ
AllowedIPs = 10.8.0.3/32

Wireguard conf on my home pc
[Interface]
PrivateKey = AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
Address = 10.8.0.3/32

[Peer]
PublicKey = BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB
AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0
Endpoint = 11.22.33.44:51820
PersistentKeepalive = 25

I also have UFW installed on the VPS (no firewall on my home pc) using which I am port forwarding 80 from the internet to my home pc.
     To                         Action      From
     --                         ------      ----
[ 1] Anywhere                   ALLOW IN    10.8.0.0/24                     
[ 2] 51820/udp                  ALLOW IN    Anywhere                   
[ 3] 51820/udp (v6)             ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)

/etc/ufw/before.rules
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
-A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.8.0.3:80
-A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 443 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.8.0.3:443
-A OUTPUT -o lo -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.8.0.3:80
-A OUTPUT -o lo -p tcp --dport 443 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.8.0.3:443
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/24 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT

Using these configurations, I am able to access my website using my domain from the internet (browser on my phone with different network) and my vps (tested via curl -4 -v my.domain). However, when I perform curl -4 -v my.domain from my home pc (10.8.0.3), I get the following error:
root@home-pc:~# curl -4 -v my.domain
*   Trying 11.22.33.44:80...
* connect to 11.22.33.44 port 80 failed: Connection refused
* Failed to connect to my.domain port 80 after 25 ms: Couldn't connect to server
* Closing connection 0
curl: (7) Failed to connect to my.domain port 80 after 25 ms: Couldn't connect to server

I know that I can directly connect to my website from my home pc using localhost (or 192.168.50.2) but I am unable to figure out why I cannot connect to my home pc via the VPN. I would like to do this because then I want to connect to localhost using my.domain. How can I achieve this? Thanks in advance for any leads.

Just after I posted this question, I was struck by a solution: Edit /etc/hosts or dnsmasq file on my home pc to allow my.domain to connect to localhost. But I am still curious why this doesn't work within the wireguard tunnel.

I believe it's because your port forwards are forwarding for eth0 interface ... however, when you connect to that VPS through your wireguard connection, you are connecting on the VPS wg0 (or whatever you've called the wireguard interface on the VPS)

@JaromandaX how can I instead forward on all interfaces?

I have tried -A PREROUTING -i wg0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.8.0.3:80 but it still doesnt work and connection times out.

at a guess, you want NAT reflection - see this

I have fixed it by adding static routes (exceptions) to the wireguard configuration on my home pc, as follows:
[Interface]
PrivateKey = AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
Address = 10.8.0.3/32

# static routes
PreUp = ip route add 11.22.33.44 via 10.44.49.1 dev eth0
PostDown = ip route del 11.22.33.44 via 10.44.49.1 dev eth0


[Peer]
PublicKey = BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB
AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0
Endpoint = 11.22.33.44:51820
PersistentKeepalive = 25

One caveat is that I will now be unable to connect to my webserver directly from the VPS but it is not a requirement for me now.
